# odata webapi call timeout "occasionally"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6, odata

My question is about odata-v4, web API with C# (Entity Framework) and MSSQLServer. I use postman to invoke the HTTP call and most of the time it works to return a result set from SQL view (~60,000 records).

However after some time, like 15 or 30 mins, the call will be a timeout. I found that if I remove $count=true (get row count of the result set), the call will be a success immediately otherwise timeout. I keep retry and after some time, the call will work again even though $count=true applied. Meanwhile, the SQL DB data and no. of records remain unchanged and the no. of SQL connection is under 50.

I am so confused having this performance issue. Please help.

I googled a forum and found a user also has a simular problem about "get row count with $inlinecount=allpages results in a timeout" but nothing help.
https://www.telerik.com/forums/disable-inlinecount

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome.